# Null hypothesis is the opposite of study hypothesis or the one which states no difference

Tags: hypothesis-testing

My study hypothesis is that drug A will be at least 10% better than drug B. The most appropriate null hypothesis for this should be 1 or 2?

1. Drug A is not at least 10% better than drug B (i.e., the opposite of the study hypothesis)
2. Drug A and drug B are not different (0% difference)

I believe that option 1 is correct. Am I right?

Comment: I feel we need more information about the data for which you want to run your test and the type of test. But typically, the null hypothesis states that there is no effect (drug A equals drug B in your case) and the alternative hypothesis states that the population value is different from the null hypothesis. So, the test will determine whether you can reject the null hypothesis in favor of the alternative hypothesis.

Your first option seems to me challenging to develop because you are making assumptions on the effect size... which is strongly linked to the nature of your data.

Comment: I used this effect size to calculate the sample size. Hence, I assumed that the null hypothesis should be relevant to this effect size alone. In truth, I am just trying to prove that drug A is better than drug B.

Comment: null hypothesis would be that Drug A<=DrugB, is 10% the confidence interval?

Answer (score 2):

The null hypothesis should be stated in a way that it
implies a specific probability distribution (called the 'null' distribution), which is used to compute the P-value.

*In general,* the alternative might be one-sided or two-sided.

Two-sided: $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B$ against $H_a: \mu_A \ne \mu_B.$

Right-sided: $H_0: \mu_A \le \mu_B$ (or $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B);$
against alternative $H_a: \mu_A > \mu_B.$

Left-sided: $H_0: \mu_A \ge \mu_B$ (or $H_0: \mu_A = \mu_B);$
against alternative $H_a: \mu_A < \mu_B.$

*Based on the information provided,* you need the left-sided alternative. Notice that the null hypothesis contains an $=$-sign
in all of the formulations---whether as $=, \ge,$ of $\le.$
[Different authors have various preferences about this.]

In any case, you should choose Answer (2).

The effect size (10% or whatever)
can be determined after you have data. If you want to be reasonably sure
to detect an effect of a particular size, then you need to do a 'power and sample size' procedure to see how many subjects should be used in the study.

I agree with @Pitouille that specifying the desired effect as "10%" better may lead to confusion. Ten percent of *what?* (More increase in red blood cells? decrease in blood sugar level? decrease in patient complaints of pain? increase in patient 'recovery"?

What will you do if the data from the study show a clear indication of "8%" better?
Abandon Drug A as useless? do a new study a double the dosage?
What will you do if Drug A shows slightly better results, but
not by quite enough to be statistically significant at the desired level?  These are important considerations that should influence the design of the study, but usually not for inclusion in the statement of $H_0.$

Comment: Do you have a huge problem with the $10\%$ better part of the question? The way I see it, it seems straightforward, at first, to take $10\%$ of the value (I guess the mean) of drug B, but we know we didn’t get exactly the population value of drug B’s mean. Then the sample statistics make it into the null hypothesis. (I suppose the percentage difference could make sense if we are dealing with proportion data. $A=0.7$ and $B=0.65$ isn’t good enough, because $A$ only beats $B$ by $0.05$ instead of the desired $10\%=0.10$.)

Comment: "do a new study a double the dosage"? Yes. Drugs do not give all or none effects and so statistical analyses that give all or none ('significant' or not) are not particularly helpful without thoughtful consideration. The habit of assuming that a singular statistical analysis (or a singular experiment) can reveal a truth is dangerous.

Comment: For the sample size calculation, I had assumed that the response rate with drug A will be at least 10% higher than drug B (absolute difference). That is why I had assumed that the null hypothesis would mean that the response rate with drug A is not at least 10% higher than drug B. If my study fails to reject this null hypothesis, the response rate of drug A can be: (1) better than drug B by a value <10%, (2) can be equal to drug B, (3) can be worse than drug B. 

From the responses here, I believe that some of my assumptions may have been incorrect.

Comment: It is useful to distinguish between errors of Type I and II.  Type I error is to reject $H_0$ when it is true, and Type II is failing to reject $H_0$ when it $H_a$ is true. Significance level $\alpha$ is P(Type I) and power is 1 - PIType II). // State null and alternative first (where alternative includes 'research' hypothesis). Then determine rejection region for desired significance level. Finally, approx sample size req'd for reasonable power. Following this sequence helps to clarify null, alt hyp, sig level, power, and sample size. They are related, but you're entangling them needlessly.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your clarifying comments along the way.